# How to bulk upload RuleSets for Azure Frontdoor

Tags: azure, azure-front-door

In Azure Frontdoor, how can we bulk import/export Rulesets?

I am looking for a way to create a CSV/Excel file with all the redirection URLs that I want to configure on my site and want to import all of them at once in Frontdoor.

Comment: Have you tried any ways? if any please share the error screenshots. it could be helpful for replication.

Comment: @SwarnaAnipindi... I haven't found any option on the site to bulk upload the rulesets. Hence the question.